# How can I add a hover class to an element?

Tags: javascript, ajax, mootools

In my CSS I have:

```
li.sort:hover {color: #F00;}
```

All my `LI` elements under the `sort` class function properly when the DOM is ready.

If I create a **new** `LI` element (using mootools `el.addClass(classname)`) I can set the base class, but can't figure out how to add a `hover` class to it.

Any ideas?

Comment: The MyClass:hover does not work on new elements, seems all browsers just don't consider such pseudo-class on newly inserted DOM elements. I had to work around this problem by means of adding a new event handler for the `mouseover` and `mouseleave` events and add/remove a regular MyHover class to the element. Not ideal, but works.

Answer (score 8):

The hover pseudoclass can be defined ahead of time in the stylesheet based on the classname that you're specifying.  Such as:

```
li.classname:hover {color:#F000;}
```

So it's defined the same way, via the stylesheet.  You would just plan ahead, knowing that you'll be defining the class name on JS-generated LI tags with a certain class, and style for it despite the fact that the list items don't exist until you create them with JavaScript.

Answer (score 4):

Hover class is added automatically when you add the non hover class. E.g. if you have

```
.MyClass
{
...
}

.MyClass:hover
{
...
}
```

just add the `MyClass`, and the `MyClass:hover` will work.

Comment: Class and id names can't start with a capital letter.

Comment: XML tag names and attributes should be all lowercase, but I've never heard that IDs and class names cannot be capitalized? What specification is that from?

Comment: Classes and ids can start with capital letters. http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/global.html#h-7.5.2

Answer (score 2):

`:hover` is not a class, but is a pseudo-selector that will select any elements the mouse is currently hovering over. If you create an `li` element, and add the `sort` class to it, then whenever you move your mouse over the element, the `li.sort:hover` rule should be activated, if the browser is working correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Not all browsers will accept the hover pseudo class on all elements.  You should consider using javascript for this effect.  jQuery for example, makes this very easy.

Answer (score 0):

> Not all browsers will accept the hover pseudo class on all elements. You should consider using javascript for this effect. jQuery for example, makes this very easy.

To be more specific, IE6 only picks up :hover styles on anchor (a) elements.