# Creating a dynamic :hover pseudoclass throught Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, pseudo-class

After looking at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/817155/how-can-i-add-a-hover-class-to-an-element), I am wondering how to do the oposite.

I already have a main class for a button I want to create, for each button I will set a different background through `myButton.style.backgroundImage`. But then I need to also set up and individual background on :hover for each different button I have.

How can I access the :hover pseudoclass through Javascript to add the specific background?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The :hover pseudoclass  is a feature of CSS.

So in your style sheet you could add.

```
.myButtonClass1:hover {background: red;}
.myButtonClass2:hover {background: blue;}
```

Alternatively if you really want to use javascript assuming you have jQuery available you could use

```
$(".myButtonClass1").hover(
  function () {
    $(this).css("background", "red");
  },
  function () {
    $(this).css("background", "none");
  }
);

$(".myButtonClass2").hover(
  function () {
    $(this).css("background", "blue");
  },
  function () {
    $(this).css("background", "none");
  }
);
```

Comment: thanks, I'm not familiar with jQuerry just yet but that would've been a good option. I guess I will treat that through javascript events, even though I have to think about touch events too.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the pseudoclass CSS (e.g. by document.write'ing it in JS) or you can use Javascript events to set the backgroundImage on hover (mouseenter/mouseleave).  The pseudoclass is automatically invoked and there isn't a way to manually 'activate' it or even 'access' it for style modifications, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `myButton.style.backgroundImage` to set the background image, instead add a separate class to each button, for example `firstButton.className += ' first-button'`

Then you can style both states for each button in CSS:

```
.first-button {
    background-image: url('first.png');
}  
.first-button:hover {
    background-image: url('first_hovered.png');
}
```

Comment: thanks for the advice but that doesn't interest me too much, I'm making a game and changing scenes so I rather create things dynamically. Having a huge CSS libraby for every element on the game seems overwhelming to me.